# jquery form plugin response stripped out tags in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

Stuck on a weird issue using [jQuery From Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). The issue I'm seeing only occurs in IE. Issue being that ajax response while using IE would have form tag stripped out.

```
<form id="the-form" method="post" action="url">
    // Fields
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<input type="hidden" id="_keepDialog" />
```

And script:

```
$('#the-form input[type="submit"]').click( function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('#the-form').ajaxSubmit({ 
        sucess: function (html) {
            alert(html.indexOf('_keepDialog'));
        }
    });
};
```

This would be used inside a jQuery dialog. Once dialog is shown, the content is loaded from exact same url using $.ajax. Content comes back fine on that call. But when the submission takes place through .ajaxSubmit the html coming back in response lacks the outer-most tags and this only happens in IE. I used fiddler to check what was being transmitted in background and the correct response (including form and hidden tags) comes back in all cases but then something happens in jQuery that sets response to form innerHTML.

I was looking at conditional code in jQuery.form plugin that does something differently for IE but can't figure it out.

Alerted value for above code will be -1 for any IE browser and greater than zero for any other browser.

Comment: same problem here, no solution :(

Answer (score 0):

Be advised that this is voodoo, but what worked for me is to add an empty pre tag in front of the form tag - then IE wouldn't strip the form tag anymore...